# How will the CreatedBy & ModifiedBy fields get populated incase we allow external users to send emails to a sharepoint list

Tags: 2013, list, configuration, incoming-email, smtp

I am working on SharePoint server 2013, and i have added an Announcement list. then i configure the announcement list to receive in-coming emails from external users (users not defined inside our active directory). But my question is how will the CreatedBy & ModifiedBy fields get populated for an item, when an email is received inside the list? as the external user will not be registered inside the Active Directory ? will these be equal to the external user email address for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will be populated with "System Account".

Comment: so if the user is not register inside active directory it will get "System Account"? for example if we configure our "info@compnay.com" email to be routed to our SharePoint server list, then if external user send an email, then the item's createdby & modifiedby will be equal to "System Account", while if internal user send an email from our domain email such as user.A@comapny.com to info@comapny.com then the createdby & modifiedby will be equal to the internal user name ??? is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, if SharePoint can *resolve* the name it will show as the display name of the user. If not, it will show as System Account.

Answer (score 1):

If users are required to authenticate then it would be the "username" probably email in case of sharepoint online or if they are not required to authenticate then it would be "Guest Contributor" in the modified field.

more detail [here](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/ultimate-guide-deal-with-office-365-external-sharing) and [here](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=cYpuAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA347&lpg=PA347&dq=sharepoint%20online%20external%20users%20%22Guest%20contributor%22&source=bl&ots=zvLLhhLo6e&sig=lVwINYyhGkcO1s_p6Kt2M2fkoY4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAwvyn4NfKAhUn5KYKHb0qAXMQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=sharepoint%20online%20external%20users%20%22Guest%20contributor%22&f=false)

Comment: now i configure the SharePoint list to "Accept e-mail messages from any sender "  under the "E-mail security policy".. so in this case no authntication is required is this correct ?

Comment: no authentication means, you are allowing external people to access your shared items/documents, in your case uses are not part of sharepoint, they do not need any authentication.

Comment: thanks for the reply,, now external users will send us an email through "info@company.com" we do not know the users .... and they do not have access to our SharePoint...